# Foreach with a where clause?

Tags: c#, foreach, where-clause

Is there such a structure in C# where I could say something similar to the following:

```
foreach(object obj in listofObjects where obj.property == false){
```

so that it would only iterate through a specific subset of objects in the collection?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's simple with extension mehtods:

```
foreach(object obj in listofObjects.Where(w => !w.property))
```

Comment: @MetalPhoenix this might look simple but for debugging purposes I suggest you use a helper variable anyway.

Comment: Why doing so ? Are there performance issues with having the `where` clause inside the `foreach` statement ?

Comment: Just easy to read

Answer (score 9):

You can use the method syntax

```
foreach(object obj in listofObjects.Where(obj => !obj.property))
```

It is also possible using the *query* syntax but it's not readable (to me at least):

```
foreach(object obj in (from x in listofObjects where !x.property select x))
```

If you are gonna use that I would store the query into a variable:

```
var query = (from x in listofObjects 
             where !x.property  
             select x);

foreach(var obj in query) { }
```

Comment: I always forget about the query approach because it just doesn't look very C#-like. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: It's not about readability only but rather about debuggability. Sooner or later you'll regret that `where` inside the `foreach`.

Comment: @t3chb0t You can debug that expression too by pressing F11 when it will consume the result of `Where`. It will stop exactly at `!x.property` for each element on it.

Comment: @VitorCanova sure, I know ;-) what I meant was that often you want to check the result before looping and without a helper variable it's not possible. There were numerous times when I had to take such an inline query out of the loop to debug it. I just wanted to mention this.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ:

```
foreach( var obj in listofObjects.Where( q => q.property == false ) )
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
foreach (var obj in listOfObjects.Where(o => !o.Property))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Where` extension method and a lambda. from Linq.

Ensure you have the `System.Linq` namespace referenced.

```
 foreach (var obj in listOfObjects.Where(obj => obj.property == false))
```